# InDesign script to verify spelling and grammar

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, adobe-acrobat, indesign-scripting

I was curious to know if there is a way to or a script available within InDesign (any solution alternative is preferred) that I can batch check spelling and grammatical errors with either `.indd` or `.pdf` files.  Some areas I would like to check are:

- Case errors:  aNd
- Case structure: AND should be and
- spelling: Bannana

If it could even be done I would like the script or process to correct the issue or document it to a file in `.pdf` format.  Is there a way to batch process a spelling and grammar check for `.indd` or `.pdf` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't comment on the validity of the queries you're running (how specific/abstract you'll need to make the search/replace strings will be context dependent), but the [GREP Query Manager](http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/grep_query_manager.html) script should allow you to easily set up a chain of queries. You can then pull all the .indd files together as a book (.indb file), and run the search/replace script chain on that.

If you're not too hot on GREP and want good guide, [GREP in InDesign](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596156015.do) is really useful (the guy who wrote it wrote the GREP Query Manager script as well), and was just updated this June.

EDIT: Regarding outputting recorded changes to a file, that I can't comment on. A script that outputs a .pdf seems somewhat pie-in-the-sky. There's Radish for version control (it's up at Google code) if that's any help.